# How do I set up an SQL table to efficiently and easily store multiple dates and times for single events?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, schema

I have a list of events that I wish to store the starting and ending times for in an SQL database. The *catch* is that some of the events only take place during one day whereas other events occur across multiple days.  Sometimes the events only occur once per day, and others occur multiple times (see examples below for more clarification).

**How do I set up my `Events` table to efficiently store all versions of start and end dates and times?**

#### Example data that needs to be stored in the table:

```
Event Name                        |    # of Participants    | Times and Dates
==========================================================================================================
Three-legged-race                 |          14             |    08:00 - 09:30 on Mar 23
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pie/Hot Dog Eating Contests       |           9             |    12:00 - 14:00 and
                                  |                         |    15:30 - 17:30 on Mar 23
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Decathlon                         |          37             |    10:00 - 14:00 on Mar 23
                                  |                         |    11:00 - 16:00 on Mar 24
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Daily Opening/Closing Ceremonies  |         100             |    07:50 - 08:00 and 
                                  |                         |    17:30 - 17:40 on Mar 23
                                  |                         |    07:50 - 08:00 and
                                  |                         |    17:30 - 17:40 on Mar 24
```

---

As a side note, I'm alright with storing the dates and times as Unix Datetimes if necessary, but I would prefer to store the value individually if necessary (for easier access/isolation/use later on).

### Edit:

I forgot to add that i would like the solution to be self contained in a single table.  I don't want to use SQL `joins` or `foreign keys` to combine multiple tables (like the `Events` table with an `EventsTime` table).

### Edit #2:

...and I was hoping for only two or so columns (not `start_datetime1`, `end_datetime1`, `start_datetime2`, `end_datetime2`, etc.).

Comment: The answer depends on what database you are using. You mentioned "SQL database", but there are a lot of those. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, etc. For instance, if you are using PostgreSQL, you can use an array field type which would allow you to store a history of all the previous values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a EventTime table? Which conctains something similar to below (idea):

```
EventTime (id, event_id, start_datetime, end_datetime)
```

That way you could have multiple event_id's no issue and you can have it in any format you described (across multiple days, single day etc)

Comment: Good solution, but I forgot to add a minor detail... I don't want to have to perform any joins or use foreign keys.  I would like this totally self contained.

Comment: Given your requirement, unless you don't mind having things like start_datetime1, end_datetime1, start_datetime2, end_datetime2, start_datetime3, end_datetime3, start_datetime4, end_datetime4, ...

I don't think it's quite possible... I'm not an expert though when it comes to database, so you can wait for a better solution :)

Comment: Frustrating, but that's what I was afraid of.  I had thought of the multiple `start_datetime#`, `end_datetime#` fields, but was hoping for a better alternative.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: you could also store the datetime's inside a php serialized string and save it into your db like that, and unserialize everytime you need it... Be warned though that this is not a recommendable practice at all and usually is frowned upon

Comment: If an "event" has one, two or more "start/end" times, then you absolutely have a "one-to-many" relationship between events and dates.  Which implies you definitely *should* have a separate "event time slots" table.  IMHO..

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a separate table for the dates. You then have a one-to-many relationship between events and dates. Your date table would have a reference to the id of the event. You can then fetch all of the dates for a given event by search for the event's key.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your choices would be:

1) either a start date/time (and possibly end/date time) in the same row

... or ...

2) separate rows for each time slot (and a unique "event id")

Based on what you're saying, you probably want option 2.

3) I'd further venture that maybe "time slot" should be it's own, separate table (with "event id" as the foreign key).